# Should MSVC's C4138 warning ("'*/' found outside of comment") be disabled?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

When compiling the following code with msvc2017

```
void Foo::bar(A */*a*/)
```

I get this warning:

```
foo.cpp:38: warning: C4138: '*/' found outside of comment
```

I can fix this by adding a space after the asterisk:

```
void Foo::bar(A * /*a*/)
```

however, I would have to do this in a bunch of places, and if I ever uncomment the parameter, the coding style I use won't be followed due to the extra space.

Since I don't get the same warning with gcc or clang, I'm wondering if this is a MSVC-specific quirk that can safely be disabled.

Comment: I can't see a problem with disabling the warning.  I do have to ask why you are doing this in the first place.  If these a function declarations why even provide a parameter name?  If these are definitions, why are you commenting out the parameter name?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I do that when implementing generic interfaces that don't require a particular parameter.

Comment: @Bathseba And putting a space in is too much work?

Comment: I do not see any issue with disabling this warning. This like too patronizing to me in the first place.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Yes. By the way the language defines /**/ as a space. Muhahaha. We don't like excess spaces. E.g. `>>` rather than `> >` in templates from C++11.

Comment: @Bathseba Space that makes things more readable is not excess space.

Comment: Compilers emit some warnings that are of the "Hey, you probably just shot yourself in the foot here!"  Those are good warnings, worth keeping.  The self-same compilers also emit warnings of the "Hey, we don't like your style here!"  The stylistic warnings can be squelched if the "bad" style is your team's style.  Not just a Microsoft-ism, you can find noisy cricket warnings in most compilers.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Your assertion of increased readability is a subjective one. To me `A * /*a*/` looks like a multiplication.

Comment: @Bathsheba You see a lot of multiplications in function declarations, do you?

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Yes, default arguments for example.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'd like to see an example of that.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: You want a job?

Comment: A couple ways to do this, but you'd think `A *` would be able to find the optimal path.

Comment: @NathanOliver The warning is for a function definition. I often use it to avoid the unused variable warnings like the accepted answer mentions, especially in re-implemented virtual functions where the parameter is not needed. Often I'll just remove the parameter name completely, but sometimes I like to leave it commented out for one reason or another.

Comment: @Mitch OK.  FWIW you can define a macro like `#define UNUSED(expr) do { (void)(expr); } while (0)` and call it in he function body like `UNUSED(a);` so you don't have to comment out the variable name but also suppress the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a unwarranted warning; there is nothing wrong with the code you present. In fact, commenting out variable names in function definitions *can* be useful for example when you want to suppress "unused variable" warnings in function parameters lists that are self-documenting.

1. Switch off the warning and rely on the compiler to issue a diagnostic if indeed there is a mismatched comment block in your code.
2. Submit a bug report to the compiler vendor.

Comment: There is often nothing actually grammatically wrong with code that causes warnings - that's why they are warnings, and not errors. A compiler can warn about whatever it wants - this is certainly not a bug.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Some warnings are errors though, e.g. uninitialised variables, plus some build engineers require warnings elevated to errors.

Comment: @NeilButterworth yet some of those are most often a problem (for example, uninitialized variable), while other are completely bogus. False warnings, while not making a compiler non-conformant, are a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: Am I the only one highly amused by the banter? Anyways, _"rely on the compiler to issue a diagnostic"_, this to me reads like the warning is objectively a bug. A _possible_ grammatical error should never be a warning.

Comment: Should be fixed in newer versions of MSVC: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/warning-c4138-found-outside-of-comment/1182287